# Only show view/block on nodes with certain field value when using "Content: Has taxonomy term ID"

Tags: views, 8, blocks

I've set up a view of [related content](https://www.reinisfischer.com/how-create-related-content-block-using-taxonomy-term-drupal-8) that has a block display and 2 contextual filters:

- "Content: ID" with "Exclude"
- "Content: Has taxonomy term ID" with
  "Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy
  blocks".

The block is configured to display only on nodes of a certain content type.

**Now, I only want to show the view/block on nodes where a field has a certain value. How?**

My question is similar to [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/153750/views-block-only-display-if-node-field-has-a-value). But the accepted answer — adding the field under Filter Criteria — doesn't work here, because the filter applies to the related nodes rather than the current node.

Is there a way to solve this just by modifying the view? (It seems like the sort of thing a view could do.) Or is it necessary to use a contrib module — Context or Entity Field Condition — to hide the block?